# How to multiply parent model field with current model field in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"


class Buy(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    @property
    def totalPrice(*args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.quantity * self.item.price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Buy"
```

How to find the **total price** by mulitplying **item price** in first model with **quantity** in the second model....Please help

Comment: Seems like what you have already should be good enough, what's the matter? You're missing the first argument `self` from the parameters of the `totalPrice` property

Answer (score 0):

Just make this changes in totalPrice func :

```
def totalPrice(self,*args, **kwargs):
 
        self.total_price = self.quantity * self.item.price
        return self.total_price
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you do not need `total_price` field, you can make it a property like this:

```
class Buy(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    
    @property
    def total_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.item.price
```

And access the value like this:

```
for buy in Buy.objects.all():
    print(buy.total_price)
```

**Optimized alternative:** You can also do the run time calculation by annotating it(without needing the property method):

```
from django.db.models import F

for buy in Buy.objects.annotate(total_price=F('item__price')*F('quantity')):
   print(buy.total_price)
```

**Another alternative:** Finally, if you insist on saving the value on DB, then override the `save` method:

```
class Buy(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Items, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.quantity * self.item.price
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```